# Show that $y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum ^n_{k=1}x_k \overset{n}{\rightarrow} x$ if $x_n \overset{n}{\rightarrow} x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

This seems obvious, but I can't imagine the formal outline of the proof. I just need a start here. Sorry for being a total noob.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233838/lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-sum-k-1n-x-k-x-given-lim-n-to-infty?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

if M=max|xi-x|  for i=1,2,3,4,...
so you can proove that by this way
look the picture